# Intermittently cannot connect to Beats Bluetooth headset from CLI

Tags: wireless, sound, kubuntu, bluetooth, 14.10

I have a Beats Studio Wireless bluetooth headset that intermittently cannot connect to Kubuntu 14.10. This is what is happening:

```
$ lsusb | grep -i blue
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)

$ hciconfig
hci0:   Type: BR/EDR  Bus: USB
        BD Address: 00:15:83:07:C6:5A  ACL MTU: 384:8  SCO MTU: 64:8
        UP RUNNING PSCAN ISCAN 
        RX bytes:2052 acl:0 sco:0 events:131 errors:0
        TX bytes:810 acl:0 sco:0 commands:73 errors:0

$ hcitool scan
Scanning ...
        00:11:22:00:11:59       Beats Wireless

$ bluez-simple-agent hci# 00:11:22:00:11:59
Creating device failed: org.bluez.Error.AlreadyExists: Already Exists

$ bluez-test-input connect 00:11:22:00:11:59
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/bluez-test-input", line 40, in <module>
    input.Connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 70, in __call__
    return self._proxy_method(*args, **keywords)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 145, in __call__
    **keywords)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 651, in call_blocking
    message, timeout)
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.bluez.Error.NotSupported: Operation is not supported

$ bt-audio -c  00:11:22:00:11:59
Error: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
```

If I continually click the Blueman system tray icon's "Recent Connections -> Audio Sink on Beats Wireless" option, then eventually the headset will connect.

Comment: I hate to say it, but that bluetooth dongle got bad reviews from windows users, so a different device would be the best solution, a similar device has reviews -http://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/reviews/B001EBE1LI?ie=UTF8&*Version*=1&*entries*=0

Comment: @user300665: Thanks. In fact I have already ordered a different bluetooth device so we'll see if that works. If so, I'll let you know to post your comment as an answer so that I could accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there are bluetooth dongles [which forge the Broadcom identifier](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1221995) even though they don't 100% follow the Bluetooth spec. Apparently my device, which cost $2 on ebay including shipping, is one of those.

According to the bug linked, the Ubuntu devs know about this and are even including workarounds for these devices. However, the **real solution** is to buy a higher-quality bluetooth dongle which follows the spec and does not forge its identity.